# Xamarin android webview incorrect device.width/height value

Tags: android, xamarin, android-webview

We use android webkit Webview to show different content inside the app. And we have problems with sites that rely on device.width/device.height to select desktop/mobile mode.
Xamarin android app with simple Webview activity return sizes in pixel(example for google below):
[Xamarin android: screen sizes in pixels for Google Nexus 5, API 21, 1080x1920](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTUmA.png)

However when I created the same app in Android Studio I got sizes in dpi:
[Native android: screen sizes in pixels for Google Nexus 5, API 21, 1080x1920](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jD2wE.png)

Is it a xamarin issue? Or Does it require some specific configurations to work correctly?

Comment: How do you get the device width and height? Using the JS code?

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/1649
It was resolved by setting android:targetSdkVersion to latest version.